# splitting Array with duplicates into two arrays, one for Unique and one for duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array like following simpler example:

`array = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9]`

and I would like to check and separate them into the following arrays:

```
uniqArray = [1,3,5,6,8,9]
dupArray = [[2,2],[4,4,4],[7,7,7]]
```

I have tried this

```js
let array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9]

let uniqArray = []
let dupArray = []

let tempArray = []

array.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item !== array[index + 1]) {
    uniqArray.push(item)
    if (tempArray.length > 0) {
      dupArray.push(tempArray)
      tempArray = []
    }
  } else {
    tempArray.push(item)
  }
})

console.log(uniqArray) // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
console.log(dupArray) // [ [ 2 ], [ 4, 4 ], [ 7, 7 ] ]
```

but as you can see the first instance of the duplicate stays in the uniqArray.

also tried this which actually worked but I am not sure if it is the best solution:

```js
let array = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9]

let arrayOfArrays = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[acc.length - 1].length === 0 || acc[acc.length - 1][0] === curr) {
    acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr)
  } else {
    acc.push([curr])
  }
  return acc
}
, [[]]) // [[ 1 ],[ 2, 2 ],[ 3 ],[ 4, 4, 4 ],[ 5 ],[ 6 ],[ 7, 7, 7 ],[ 8 ],[ 9 ]]



let uniqItems = arrayOfArrays.filter(item => item.length === 1).map(item => item[0]) 
let duplicateItems = arrayOfArrays.filter(item => item.length > 1) 

console.log("~ duplicateItems", duplicateItems) // [ [ 2, 2 ], [ 4, 4, 4 ], [ 7, 7, 7 ] ]
console.log("~ uniqItems", uniqItems) // [ 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 ]
```

It would be awesome if anyone has a better solution to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Map

```js
const array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9];

const countMap = new Map();
// Count the occurence of each item and save it at a map.
for (const number of array) {
  const count = countMap.get(number);
  if (count) countMap.set(number, count + 1);
  else countMap.set(number, 1);
}

const unique = [];
const double = [];

// For each item at map, fill the unique and double array
for (const keyValue of countMap.entries()) {
  const count = keyValue[1];
  const number = keyValue[0];
  if (count == 1) {
    unique.push(number);
  } else {
    double.push(Array(count).fill(number));
  }
}

console.log(unique);
console.log(double);
```

I think this is the most performatic way to do it with a large array, and it don't need to be sorted

Comment: Thank you this is much much faster than my solution. I am going to try to implement it in the actual app and see if it will still solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
def getUniqueAndDups(arr):
    c = collections.Counter(arr)
    unique = []
    dups = []
    for item in c:
        if c[item] == 1:
            unique.append(item)
        else:
            dups.append([item]*c[item])
    return unique, dups
```

---

```py
>>> uniqueArray, dupArray = getUniqueAndDups([1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9])
>>> uniqueArray
[1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
>>> dupArray
[[2, 2], [4, 4, 4], [7, 7, 7]]
>>>
```

Comment: I like this answer. I didn't know about `collections.Counter`, very cool. +1

Comment: Thanks @RyanWilson! the `collections` module has a ton of neat functions out there :) Quite pythonic too!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array = [1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9];
//sort the array
array.sort();
let unique = [];
let dupes = [];
let duptemp = [];

//iterative approach using traditional for loop
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   //if the next element in array is equal to current, add current
   //to dupes
   if(i + 1 < array.length && array[i + 1] === array[i]){
      duptemp.push(array[i]);
   //if next element in array is not equal to current
   //and duptemp is has values, push into dupes and clear temp
   } else if(i + 1 < array.length && array[i + 1] !== array[i] && duptemp.length > 0) {
      duptemp.push(array[i]);
      dupes.push(duptemp);
      duptemp = [];
   //if at the end of the array and duptemp has values,
   //add to dupes
   } else if(i + 1 >= array.length && duptemp.length > 0){
      duptemp.push(array[i]);
      dupes.push(duptemp);
   //it's unique
   } else {
      unique.push(array[i]);
   }
}

console.log(unique);
console.log(dupes);
```